# dns_get_mx, dns_get_record and checkdnsrr don't work with MX (work with A though)

Tags: php, dns

I'm trying to validate whether an MX record exists for a given domain, and nothing works.

```
// prepare the hostname
$hostname = 'gmail.com';
$hostname = idn_to_ascii($hostname);//php.net/manual/function.checkdnsrr.php#113537
$hostname = sprintf('%s.', $hostname);//php.net/manual/function.checkdnsrr.php#119969
// perform the checks
dns_get_mx($hostname, $dns_get_mx); // a.k.a. getmxrr()
$dns_get_record = dns_get_record($hostname, DNS_MX);
$checkdnsrr = checkdnsrr($hostname, 'MX');
// output the result
var_dump(array(
    'hostname' => $hostname,
    'dns_get_mx' => $dns_get_mx,
    'dns_get_record' => $dns_get_record,
    'checkdnsrr' => $checkdnsrr,
));
```

Here's what I'm getting (for both [`gmail.com.`](https://php.net/manual/function.checkdnsrr.php#119969) and `gmail.com`, tried separately):

```
Warning: dns_get_record(): A temporary server error occurred. in /var/www/html/example.php
array (size=4)
  'hostname' => string 'gmail.com.' (length=10)
  'dns_get_mx' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'dns_get_record' => boolean false
  'checkdnsrr' => boolean false
```

If I replace `MX` with `A`, [`dns_get_record()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php) returns a correct IP address, and [`checkdnsrr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php) returns `true`.

There's nothing in the logs (except for the above warning), and googling didn't help. How do I debug this?

**UPD** The issue appears in my local VirtualBox environment (PHP 5.6.39); everything actually works on the production server (PHP 7.3.11)

Comment: Some domains may not have an MX record. Also, might be because of [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73149)

Comment: Which nameservers do you use to get the reply? Did you try with others?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov I tried several domains, including ours that I know for sure has mail working. As for the bug - he tries if for a non-existing domain, and my domains are working, and if I change from MX to A, PHP is returning values just fine

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I don't know, how do I find out or use a different nameserver? Reading the docs, the above functions won't let me specify my own nameservers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox seems to be overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf`, and that messes up the DNS on the guest machine.

My fix for now is:

```
echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

[More info](https://www.google.com/search?q=virtualbox+resolv.conf)